# Base class C++14 template functions are not visible in clang on Mac os ( recursive templates)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, llvm-clang

This code can be used just fine on gcc , but it does not work on mac OS with clang 
The code is utilizing recursive templates via inheritance of next type in the typelist 
Think of a Entity => Head and Entities... => Tail...

```
template<typename ...Entities>
    struct GenericBidderCacheLoader;

    template<typename Entity, typename ...Entities>
    struct GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entity, Entities ...> :  GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entities ...> {
        using GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entities ...>::retrieve;

        template<typename Config>
        GenericBidderCacheLoader(const Config &config): GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entities...>(config), entity(config)
        {}
        void load() noexcept(false) {
           entity.load();
           GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entities...>::load();
        }

        template<typename T, typename... Keys>
        decltype(std::declval<Entity>().retrieve(std::declval<T&>(),std::declval<Keys>()...), bool())
        retrieve(T & t, Keys&& ... keys) {
            return  entity.template retrieve(t, std::forward<Keys>(keys)...);
        }

        Entity entity;
    };

template<typename Entity>
    struct GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entity> {


        template<typename Config>
        GenericBidderCacheLoader(const Config &config): entity(config)
        {}
        void load() noexcept(false) {
            entity.load();
        }

        template<typename T, typename... Keys>
        decltype(std::declval<Entity>().retrieve(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<Keys>()...), bool())
        retrieve(T & t, Keys&& ... keys) {
            return  entity.template retrieve(t, std::forward<Keys>(keys)...);
        }

        Entity entity;
    };
```

Basically GenericBidderCacheLoader holds a typeist , and inheritance model works like that GenericBidderCacheLoad<FirstType> is derived from GenericBidderCacheLoad<SecondType> which is derived from GenericBidderCacheLoad<ThirdType> Which is very common if you want to build a typelist with delegated functionality .

Use case for GenericBidderCacheLoader type is here:

```
using CacheLoader  =  vanilla::GenericBidderCacheLoader<RefererEntity<>, ICOCampaignEntity<>, AdDataEntity<BidderConfig>>;   
...
...
CacheLoader cacheLoader(config);    
 //Return from each lambda becomes input for next lambda in the tuple of functions
auto retrieve_referer_f = [&cacheLoader](const std::string& ref, auto&& ...) {
    Referer referer;
    if(!cacheLoader.retrieve(referer,ref)) {
        return boost::optional<uint32_t>();
    }
    return boost::optional<uint32_t>(referer.ref_id);
};

auto retrieve_ico_campaign_f = [&cacheLoader](boost::optional<uint32_t> ref_id, auto&& ...)  {
    std::vector<ICOCampaign> ico_campains;
    if (!cacheLoader.retrieve(ico_campains,*ref_id)) {
        return boost::optional<decltype(ico_campains)>();
    }
    return boost::optional<decltype(ico_campains)>(ico_campains);
};


auto retrieve_campaign_ads_f = [&cacheLoader](boost::optional<std::vector<ICOCampaign>> campaigns, auto && req, auto && imp)  {
    std::vector<Ad> retrieved_cached_ads;
    for (auto &campaign : *campaigns) {
        if (!cacheLoader.retrieve(retrieved_cached_ads, campaign.campaign_id, imp.banner.get().w, imp.banner.get().h)) {
            continue;
        }
        auto budget_bid = selector.authorize(cacheLoader.get_entity<CampaignCache<BidderConfig>>(), campaign.campaign_id);
        std::transform(std::begin(retrieved_cached_ads),
                       std::end(retrieved_cached_ads),
                       std::begin(retrieved_cached_ads), [budget_bid](Ad & ad){
                    ad.auth_bid_micros = std::min(budget_bid, ad.max_bid_micros);
                    return ad;
                });
    }
    if ( retrieved_cached_ads.empty() ) {
        return boost::optional<decltype(retrieved_cached_ads)>();
    }
    return boost::optional<decltype(retrieved_cached_ads)>(retrieved_cached_ads);
};
```

Error message :

```
error: no matching member function for call to
      'retrieve'
        if (!cacheLoader.retrieve(ico_campains,*ref_id)) {
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
generic_bidder_cache_loader.hpp:42:9: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with
      T = std::__1::vector<ICOCampaign, std::__1::allocator<ICOCampaign> >, Keys = <unsigned int &>]: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Referer'
      cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'std::__1::vector<ICOCampaign, std::__1::allocator<ICOCampaign> >'
        retrieve(T & t, Keys&& ... keys) {
```

In case of GCC

```
using GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entities...>::retrieve
```

Helped GCC to see those functions defined in all base classes , but clang gives up can't see them ?
Ideally it should work as following , when substitution fails SFINAE it should be able to see function in any of the derived, base-I , base-II , base-III classes.

Full implementation can be found in the temporary branch on github here 
https://github.com/venediktov/vanilla-rtb/tree/ico_bidder20171217

https://github.com/venediktov/vanilla-rtb/blob/ico_bidder20171217/examples/ico_campaign_bidder/ico_campaign_bidder_test.cpp

https://github.com/venediktov/vanilla-rtb/blob/ico_bidder20171217/rtb/datacache/generic_bidder_cache_loader.hpp

I also tried to do recursion to help Clang to see those recursive instantiated class functions

```
template<typename T, typename... Keys>
using retrieve_type = decltype(std::declval<Entity>().retrieve(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<Keys>()...)) ;

      template<typename T, typename... Keys>
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<retrieve_type<T,Keys...>,bool>::value,bool>::type
        retrieve(T & t, Keys&& ... keys) {
            return  entity.template retrieve(t, std::forward<Keys>(keys)...);
        }

        template<typename T, typename... Keys>
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entities ...>::template retrieve_type<T,Keys...>,bool>::value,bool>::type
        retrieve(T & t, Keys&& ... keys) {
            return  GenericBidderCacheLoader<Entities ...>::retrieve(t, std::forward<Keys>(keys)...);
        }
```

But it only helped clang to see the second in the typelist but not  the third , it almost the case that I had to recurse to the final type from the top level .

Comment: could you provide the clang error? I tried to [simplify the problem](https://godbolt.org/g/vnhM9J) but clang doesn't have the issue when limited to just template member functions (could be a number of things messing clang up)

Comment: Can't reproduce, please post a [mcve].

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Your simplified problem is not similar to OP's code. In fact, clang++ and g++ indeed behave differently in this issue.

Comment: @liliscent, thank you for creating minimal, Complete , and Verifiable example !

Answer (score 2):

This question lacks a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. So I haven't tested OP's code. However, by reading the quoted code piece and the error message, I constructed a minimal example which can make the different behavior between g++ and clang++ clearer:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<class U>
struct Foo
{
    template<class V>
    decltype(std::declval<U>().echo_dumb(std::declval<V>()))
    dumb(V const &v) {
        u.echo_dumb(v);
    }
    U u;
};

template<class T, class U>
struct Bar
    : public Foo<U>
{
    using Foo<U>::dumb;

    template<class V>
    decltype(std::declval<T>().echo_dumb(std::declval<V>()))
    dumb(V const &v) {
        t.echo_dumb(v);
    }
    T t;
};

struct A { void echo_dumb(A const &) {} };
struct B { void echo_dumb(B const &) {} };

int main() {
    Bar<A, B> bar;
    bar.dumb(A{}); // ok for everyone
    bar.dumb(B{}); // error for clang++, ok for g++
}
```

Thus the problem becomes "what is the semantics of `using` declaration ?".

After reading some C++ standard pages, I think clang++ has correctly rejected this code, because:

[[namespace.udecl]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl)

> The set of declarations introduced by the using-declarator is found by performing qualified name lookup ([basic.lookup.qual], [class.member.lookup]) for the name in the using-declarator, excluding functions that are hidden as described below.
>
> ...
>
> When a using-declarator brings declarations from a base class into a derived class, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a base class (rather than conflicting). Such hidden or overridden declarations are excluded from the set of declarations introduced by the using-declarator.

Since 2 `dumb` function have exactly the same parameter-type-list, the one introduced by `using` declaration is hidden and will not be included.

If the `dumb` in `Foo` has signature `dumb(V const &v, int = 0)`, then both g++ and clang++ accept this code.

What is interesting is, if we replace 2 `decltype(std::declval<U>().echo_dumb(std::declval<V>()))` by simply a `void`, then both g++ and clang++ correctly reject it, with message *no matching function*. So it seems the `decltype` part in the return part confuses g++ compiler.

Comment: Thank you for creating minimal complete example for me!  What bothers me though with SFINAE , shouldn't the function dumb only exist in Foo<B>::dumb when you call  bar.dumb(B{}); as the first substitution creating Bar<A,B>::dumb should fail and then "using-declarator" should work as prescribed no override no hide? I think  gcc is able to exclude failed template function Bar<A,B>::dumb when you called bar.dumb(B{}); ?

Comment: You need to pay attention to the order of various stage. SFINAE takes place at template at template argument substitution, which is after template argument deduction. When compiler starts checking SFINAE, the effect of *using* is already fixed.

Comment: More precisely, the order is: name lookup -> template argument deduction -> template argument substitution(SFINAE is here) -> overload resolution. `using` is doing name lookup, far before SFINAE.

Comment: What you said makes total sense , looks like gcc is confused and thinks functions are different. In your example I was able to fix compilation by adding default argument  dumb(V const &v , U*  = 0)     
dumb(V const &v , T*  = 0)  see here  https://godbolt.org/g/jhRNo2

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer , I just wanted to show how I fixed my code based on the answer from @liliscent

```
        template<typename T, typename... Keys>
        bool retrieve(T & t, Keys&& ... keys) {
            auto tuple = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Keys>(keys)...);
            return  this->retrieve(t, tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<decltype(tuple)>::value>());
        }

        template<typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Idx>
        decltype(std::declval<Entity>().retrieve(std::declval<T&>(),std::get<Idx>(std::declval<Tuple>())...), bool())
        retrieve(T & t, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Idx...>, Entity* = 0) {
            return  entity.template retrieve(t, std::get<Idx>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
        }
```

New code now compiles with both gcc and clang . I would be happy If anyone reviewed my change. This code is an open-source project available on GitHub. The links to the files in my original question are outdated if anyone wants to see the original problem please click on revision history.

And with sizeof... operator it's even shorter

```
    template<typename T, typename... Keys>
    bool retrieve(T & t, Keys&& ... keys) {
        return  this->retrieve(t, std::make_tuple(std::forward<Keys>(keys)...),
                                  std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(keys)>()
                               );
    }

    template<typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Idx>
    decltype(std::declval<Entity>().retrieve(std::declval<T&>(),std::get<Idx>(std::declval<Tuple>())...), bool())
    retrieve(T & t, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Idx...>, Entity* = 0) {
        return  entity.template retrieve(t, std::get<Idx>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))...);
    }
```